# using local and ormap

Tags: list, scheme, local, racket

```
(define (find-name s los)
  (cond [(empty? los) false]
        [(cons? los)
         (ormap
          (local
            ((define robot s))
            ))])))
```

Basically this consumes a name and a list of names and determines whether any of the names 
on the latter are equal

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am using ISL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ormap` procedure expects a procedure as its first argument, and it takes care of iterating over the list (no need to do it by hand). Also, I'm not sure why you're using `local` in the first place. Perhaps you intended to write something like this?

```
(define (find-name s los)
  (ormap (lambda (e)
           (or (equal? s e) (string-contains? s e)))
         los))
```

EDIT: Well, you *could* use `local`, but it's more idiomatic to simply pass a `lambda`. Here's how:

```
(define (find-name s los)
  (local [(define (f e) (or (equal? s e) (string-contains? s e)))]
    (ormap f los)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way you can use local for this problem?

Comment: @Josh it's not _that_ idiomatic but yes, you could use it. See my edited answer.